# Why these layout issues occur when debugging view hierarchy while the UI layout in simulator is OK

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-autolayout

I use visual format to layout subviews in cell like this:

```
contentView.addSubview(accountLabel)
contentView.addSubview(contentLabel)
contentView.addSubview(timeLabel)

let views: [String : Any] = [
    "accountLabel": accountLabel,
    "contentLabel": contentLabel,
    "timeLabel": timeLabel
]

let hConstraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-15-[accountLabel]-[timeLabel]-8-|", options: [.alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: views)
let hConstraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[contentLabel]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
let vConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-12-[accountLabel]-8-[contentLabel]-12-|", options: [.alignAllLeading], metrics: nil, views: views)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(hConstraint1+hConstraint2+vConstraint)
```

And it looks ok when run in simulator:

[image]

However, some layout issues occur when debugging view hierarchy:

[image]

Why these layout issues occur while the runtime UI looks ok?

Is something wrong with the visual format string above? Or it's the bug of Xcode?

How to remove these layout issues?

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: @user1000 The controller and tableView is created in storyboard. The cell is created by code.

Comment: Are you using `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`? By the way - please don't post screen-caps of your code... post the code itself (that way, if someone wants to try and replicate your condition, we can copy/paste it).

Comment: @DonMag Yeah, I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. What's the problem? By the way, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @DonMag I have updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I'm not an expert with constraints, but I do see one "correctable" issue and one "that's just weird maybe it's a bug" issue.

As I understand it, auto-layout will try to satisfy the constraints -- *even if they are ambiguous*. If it **fails**, then you see the error message in the console, usually along the lines of "will attempt to satisfy by breaking..."

So the warning information you see in `Debug View Hierarchy` is more informational than "fix this error" directive.

That said...

---

You have `accountLabel` and `timeLabel` constrained relative to each other, but they both have the same `Compression Resistance`. So, as long as the amount of text in each label would "fit", all is OK.

But suppose the `accountLabel` gets a text string of "This user name is too long to fit here"?

Should it look like this (I use background colors to help see the frames):

[image]

or like this:

[image]

That's why the horizontal position and width is showing as "ambiguous".

You can fix that issue by adding one line. Assuming you want `accountLabel` to be truncated:

```
    accountLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(749, for: .horizontal)
```

will do the trick. The default is `750`, so that line tells auto-layout to give `timeLabel` the higher Resistance.

---

The Height and Vertical positions showing as ambiguous don't seem right. I don't see anything wrong with the constraints.

If I use the same font for all three labels? ***No*** ambiguous warnings.

If I use a different font size for the `timeLabel` (as you show in your images), now there ***are*** warnings in debug view hierarchy.

***Except...*** If I scroll so the cells are reused? The warnings have gone away!

**EDIT:** As the OP states in his comment, the Vertical ambiguity can be eliminated (prior to scrolling) by giving different `Content Hugging Priority` values to `accountLabel` and `contentLabel`.

Since the default `Hugging` priority is `250`:

```
    accountLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(249, for: .vertical)
```

Clears that warning.

I'm not convinced it's **necessary**... but it *does* appear to do the job.

Comment: @DonMag Follow your thought, I change the vertical `contentHuggingPriority` of `contentLabel` to be higher than the default value 250. Then, the warnings go away! Actually, when the vertical `contentHuggingPriority` of the `contentLabel` and `accountLable` is different, the warnings will go away. You may update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @a_tuo - I sure thought I gave that a try... but obviously not, as it does the job. I updated my answer.